# Wordpress: Using get_current_user_id() Inserted into my WPDB table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, insert

So I would like my plugin to insert the current user's ID into my table, "wp_ml_char".
The problem is, it's failing to actually insert it; nothing happens and no errors are displayed. This form is only asking me to put in a name, but it also has a "hidden" input type which grabs whatever user ID is currently present. I can't pinpoint where the cause is exactly, but it might be the "hidden" input line I made. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

```
 // Character creation form. Grab the current user's ID.
require_once('/home/mythlarp/public_html/wp-includes/user.php');
$wpid = get_current_user_id();

function html_form_code() {
    echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="wp_id" value="<?php echo $wpid; ?>" />';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Character Name (required) <br />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="ml_char_name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" value=""' . ( isset( $_POST["ml_char_name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["ml_char_name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"/></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}

// Insert form data.
$wpdb->insert('$table_name', array(
    'ml_char_name' => $_POST['ml_char_name'],
    'wp_id' => $_POST['wp_id'],
));
```

Here is what the form looks like.
[image: Character creation form.]
Here is what the table looks like.
[image]

Comment: $_POST['wp_id'] is not save in wp_id ?

Comment: 1. First things first, don't hard code file paths.
Change the first line to:
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/user.php');

2. I am assuming the $wpdb->insert code is in another files which processes the file submission (i.e. index.php).

Can you do a `var_dump($_POST)` to check what data is $POST actually carrying over?

Comment: So, require_once brings a function from user.php called "get_current_user_id" https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/. $wpid calls that function, which should give me the current Wordpress user's ID. Then I put the $wpid variable in my form so that when a Wordpress member submits a character name.

Comment: I did the var_dump($_POST) like you have asked shariqkhan, but I got "0", which means it didn't find a logged in user ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try write your function like this

```
function html_form_code($wpid) {
    echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="wp_id" value="'.$wpid.'" />';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Character Name (required) <br />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="ml_char_name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" value=""' . ( isset( $_POST["ml_char_name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["ml_char_name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"/></p>';
    echo '</form>';


}
```

Comment: This is on the right track, but it still doesn't insert the data into my table. I'm going to take smaller steps for inserting data to see where the problem lies. Thank you Akhil.